# Where do I declare jQuery functions in Durandal Project?

Tags: durandal

I have the following view:

```
define(['durandal/http','plugins/router','knockout'], function (http,router,ko) {

function actionItem(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ActionID = data.ActionID;
    self.Heading = data.Heading;
}

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Actions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.People = [
        'My Actions',
        'Everyones Actions'
    ];
    self.Whats = [
        'Outstanding Actions',
        'Completed Actions',
        'All Actions'
    ];
    self.Hows = [
        'Entry',
        'Alphabetical',
        'Deadline'
    ];
    self.activate = function () {
        return http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/actions/getactions?who=" + self.People[0] + "&what=" + self.Whats[0] + "&how=" + self.Hows[0])
            .done(function (allData) {
                var mapped = $.map(allData, function (list) { return new actionItem(list); });
                self.Actions(mapped);
            });
    };
    self.viewAttached = function () {
        $("#cboWhat").change(function () {
            alert("test");
        });
    };
}

var model = new viewModel();
return model;

});
```

The page works and data is loaded ok from activate function, but wherever I put the jQuery function to monitor the select change event it doesn't get called.  There are no errors and it would seem the viewAttached function is not even called. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who comes across this same issue, it seems version 2 of Durandal does not use viewAttached but simply attached instead.  Changed self.viewAttached to self.attached and all working.

Also navigateTo is now just navigate in version 2.